# Make a read only filesystem for one specific user (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: 18.04, server, permissions, users, read-only

How do I make a read only filesystem for one user only? For example, root would have full access to the system, but a user I create called `bob` only has access to his home directory?

Comment: Bob by default and by definition only has access to his home directory, unless he's also root,

Comment: Really? I didn't know this. So bob can't edit any files outside of his home directory?

Comment: By default no, he can't. Exceptions are some external media automatically mounted in /media. FAT32 is the typical file system in such media and it doesn't support permissions.

Comment: Alright, one last question: If bob were to run rm -rf /* what would it delete?

Comment: Nothing: Permission denied. Although anybody I discovered trying it on my system might find their account suspended.

Comment: In the question it reads "...`bob` only has access to his home directory", which I take to mean `bob` cannot **access** meaning `read` outside of the user's home directory. So, are you actually asking whether `bob` can `read` outside the home directory or `write` outside the home directory?

Comment: I'm asking how to make bob only have perms to read the entire filesystem (other than the vital parts like ram and stuff because everything in linux is a file).

Comment: What do you want `bob` to do in the home directory of user `bob`?

Comment: Just view it. Bob shouldn't be able to create/edit files

Comment: I haven't tested this, but I think an easy way to achieve this is just run `sudo chown -R root:root /home/bob` and `bob` should still be able to log in, but not be able to do anything other than `read`, since `bob` already can't `write` outside the user home directory.

Comment: Alright! I'll try that and let you know if it works.

Comment: Yep! That works perfectly. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User `bob` already cannot write outside of `/home/bob`, so it is necessary to make `/home/bob` not writeable by user `bob`:

```
$ sudo chown -R root:root /home/bob
```

If `bob` is logging in using `ssh` with public key, then `bob` still needs keys readable by `bob`:

```
$ sudo chmod 400 /home/bob/.ssh/authorized_keys
$ sudo chown bob /home/bob/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

And make sure that `/home/bob/.ssh` has permissions `755`:

```
$ sudo ls -alhF /home/bob/.ssh
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 28 17:12 ./
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Apr 28 17:16 ../
-r-------- 1 bob  root 2314 Apr 28 17:12 authorized_keys
```